# Require one state or another state with salt

Tags: automation, salt-stack

I'm looking since several hours for a technic to write a salt state wich requires **requirement1** or **requirement2**.

That's what I would like to do with cmd.run for example:

```
Run myscript:
  cmd.run:
    - name: /path/to/myscript
    - require: 
      - pkgs: pkg1|pkg2
    - cwd: /
```

Which means The script my_script will be executed if the state installing the package **pkg1** or the state installing the **pkg2** is satisfied.

Can this be really be done with salt? If so how?

I know I can make all my checks in my script directly, but I wanted to know if **salt requisites** could do that cleverly.

Thanks.

Comment: try this: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html

Comment: you have the `require` keyword there,which could help you

Comment: I see you're not getting me @tudoricc, I know the **require** keyword. I use it every time, I'm talking about a special use, which is to define two requistes, and run a command or any other state is at least one of the requisites is satisfied. Read my post well please. Are you getting what I mean?
Thanks

Comment: ok,sorry for the misunderstanding.So what you want to do is check if pkg1 `or` pkg2 exists.did you try `onlyif` together with `rpm --quiet -qi package1 || rpm --quiet -qi package2`

Comment: @papiveron, could you please provide details on your specific example when you want to run your script with one or another package? I cannot think of example when this choice is not system specific (or when it is actually script-specific that it should actually be determined in the script anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt states do not support branching `if`/`else`/`while`/ etc. The states file redered into a data which describes static dependency trees. Once rendered, the execution is performed in order.

The only way to do some sort of branching is to use `unless`/`onlyif` keywords. But they only work with specific state types and **do not accept** state ids (AFAIK, they only accept executable shell commands). See: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#unless

Comment: can you take a look at what I wrote him as a comment to his question?[the last thing,I think might work just as well for him]

Comment: Ok @uvsmtid, as I thought since the beginning, what I want is not possible with salt states.

Comment: Ok, this confirms as I thought since the beginning, that what I want is not possible with salt states.

And yes @tudoricc, what you suggest is what I had already except that I'm not on redhat or on a system using rpm package management system. And it's the same thing he is saying. But personnaly I prefere to make my checks in my script then, because what you suggest above with the **onlyif rpm.......*** is not realy portable, and will not work if there is no rpm on the system.
Regards.